# MySQL error code 1235

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1235

In MySQL I tried to define a trigger like this:

```sql
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE TRIGGER vipInvite  
AFTER INSERT ON meetings  
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN     
IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM participants 
   WHERE meetid = NEW.meetid AND pid ='vip'))
    THEN  
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE meetid = NEW.meetid AND slot > 16))  
    THEN  
    INSERT INTO participants(meetid, pid) 
    VALUES (NEW.meetid,(SELECT userid 
    FROM   people WHERE people.group = 'tap' GROUP BY invite));  
END IF;  
END IF;  
END $$  
DELIMITER ;
```

Produces this error:

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table.

Is there a way to work around this so I can define multiple triggers?

Comment: As mentioned https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105578/error-this-version-of-mariadb-doesnt-yet-support-multiple-triggers-with-the-s

MySQL 5.7.2 and MariaDB 10.2.3 support multiple triggers on the same action time and event

Answer (score 31):

This error means you already have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `meetings` table.

If it is the same trigger (meaning `vipInvite`) that you created earlier and now you want to replace it then you need to drop it first

```
DROP TRIGGER vipInvite;
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE TRIGGER vipInvite
...
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now if you have some other trigger you have to merge code from both triggers into one, then drop existing trigger, and then create a new one.

To show the list of existing triggers use [`SHOW TRIGGERS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-triggers.html).

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `table` = 'meetings';
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to reproduce this error in MySQL:**

```
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple 
triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

Run the following queries:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger1 AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
END//

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger2 AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
END//
```

If you want to hook more than one action onto the same event/table, you will have to cram all of it into one trigger.  You could call many stored procedures like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger1 AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL fromulate_the_moobars(NEW.myid);
    CALL its_peanut_butter_jelly_time(NEW.myname);
END//
```