# MySQL Error 1235

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1235

I am getting MySQL error 1235, and have already tried all the solutions I could find on SO.

```
 --
 -- Trigger `buying_tasks`
 -- DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `lock_user_of_task_buying_task` BEFORE INSERT ON  `buying_tasks`  FOR EACH ROW UPDATE  `users` SET locked =1
 WHERE id = NEW.user_id$$
```

With Error

```
   #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

Here is the full action:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `lock_user_of_task_buying_task` BEFORE INSERT ON `buying_tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `users` SET locked = 1 WHERE id = NEW.user_id
$$
DELIMITER ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `unlock_user_of_task_buying_task` AFTER DELETE ON `buying_tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `users` SET locked = 0 WHERE id = OLD.user_id
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is a dump of my old database file I am trying to import.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016297/mysql-error-code-1235

Comment: Already tried the solutions there.

Comment: Did you try END$$ instead of only $$ before DELIMITER ; ?
 see : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: Read this too : http://www.lemiffe.com/5-solutions-for-mysql-error-1235/

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Hew... And what about defining the delimiter only once and use it between you queries... Like here : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/12/27/mysql-how-to-change-delimiter-in-mysql-supporting-go-keyword-of-sql-server-in-mysql/ To be honest, I'm searching the web with you on this.

Comment: Nope, here is what I am trying now: http://pastebin.com/RzHrNWX4

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I also see no other BEFORE INSERT anywhere in the file.

Comment: Have you Tryed «BEFORE UPDATE» and «AFTER UPDATE» instead of the insert and delete event that do not occur anyway ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The only BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE
http://pastebin.com/g9eEaDpS

Comment: I'm getting lost. Your Pastebin changed a lot. I just found a mySQL debugger that may be usefull to you : https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html Good luck!

Comment: Your code is correct. Please check if your triggers exists already:
`show triggers where ``table`` like 'buying_tasks';` If they don't exist, please check again.

Comment: @Solarflare http://i.imgur.com/guyJHu5.png

Comment: @Jame Your screenshot shows your triggers have been created. I'm a little confused as to what is your problem.

Comment: Me too, if it is creating them why would it error?

Comment: When will it give the error exactly? When you run your code/import again after they are already there? That can't be, since you "have already tried all the solutions I could find on SO.", and dropping the trigger before creating them again should be the first solution you should find for this problem on SO. But just in case you didn't find that by yourself and didn't bother to read the link in the first comment with the same obvious solution: DROP your already existing trigger before you create them again! If that doesn't solve it: Please describe in detail what you are doing.